# Equations of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Say, I have a system at rest. I was wondering - how many equations of motion can the system have (without redundancy)? Well, I thought that equating the forces along 2 or 3 different axes would give 3 independent equations. Also equating torques would give some equations, but how many of them (independent) can I formulate? Kindly help me.

Comment: You can describe a system at rest as dx/dt=0. But asking how many independent descriptions can be formulated seems to me like asking how many descriptions can be done of a rock.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "at rest" is only true in one reference frame, so equations of motion aren't going to ensure it.

Say the phase space dimension is $2n$, so there are $n$ canonical coordinates each with a conjugate momentum. Dynamically, there are $n$ second-order Euler-Lagrange equations or $2n$ first-order Hamilton's equations. "At rest" is a first-order statement, so we'll use the Hamiltonian formalism. There is no force, so non-relativistically we can take the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ so $\dot{p}_i=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}=0,\,\dot{q}_i=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}=\frac{p_i}{m}$. But this still only gives us a second-order constraint on $q$, namely $\ddot{q}=0$. This shouldn't surprise us, because the equivalent Lagrangian formalism would never have obtained $\dot{q}=0$.

But if you don't care about Lagrangian or Hamiltonian mechanics obtaining the fact that $\dot{q}=0$, you could characterise this fact as $n$ conditions, which can more elegantly be stated as $p=0$. When momentum is conserved, as in this case, we can choose a fixed value for $p$ with a reference frame choice.

Comment: Could you add something about how this applies to rigid bodies as well as systems of particles? Something like "for a system of $N$ particles in 3 dimensions $n=3N$ while for a system of $N$ rigidbodies $n=6N$".